# combine states for a rating component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

I am trying to make a star rating component. I am using ternary operators to check if a state is true or not. If yes, I use a yellow star or else a white one. However, this looks like bad code practice. Instead of repeating all these ternary operators, is it possible to somehow combine the conditions and render only those yellow stars whose state is true?

```
const [oneStar, setOneStar] = useState(false);
const [twoStar, setTwoStar] = useState(false);
const [threeStar, setThreeStar] = useState(false);
const [fourStar, setFourStar] = useState(false);
const [fiveStar, setFiveStar] = useState(false);

const ratings = [
    1,2,3,4,5
]

const setRating = (rating: number) => {
  console.log('rating', rating);
  if(rating == 1){
      setOneStar(true);
      setTwoStar(false);
      setThreeStar(false);
      setFourStar(false);
      setFiveStar(false);
  }
  if(rating == 2){
    setOneStar(true);
    setTwoStar(true);
    setThreeStar(false);
    setFourStar(false);
    setFiveStar(false);
}
if(rating == 3){
    setOneStar(true);
    setTwoStar(true);
    setThreeStar(true);
    setFourStar(false);
    setFiveStar(false);
}
if(rating == 4){
    setOneStar(true);
    setTwoStar(true);
    setThreeStar(true);
    setFourStar(true);
    setFiveStar(false);
}
if(rating == 5){
    setOneStar(true);
    setTwoStar(true);
    setThreeStar(true);
    setFourStar(true);
    setFiveStar(true);
}
};

return (
<View style={styles.ratingContainer}>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setRating(1)}>
        {oneStar ? 
      <Icon name= "star" color='#ebba34' size={moderateScale(13)} /> : <Icon name= "star-o" size={moderateScale(13)} />}
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setRating(2)}>
        {twoStar ? 
      <Icon name= "star" color='#ebba34' size={moderateScale(13)} /> : <Icon name= "star-o" size={moderateScale(13)} />}
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setRating(3)}>
        {threeStar ? 
      <Icon name= "star" color='#ebba34' size={moderateScale(13)} /> : <Icon name= "star-o" size={moderateScale(13)} />}
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setRating(4)}>
        {fourStar ? 
      <Icon name= "star" color='#ebba34' size={moderateScale(13)} /> : <Icon name= "star-o" size={moderateScale(13)} />}
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setRating(5)}>
        {fiveStar ? 
      <Icon name= "star" color='#ebba34' size={moderateScale(13)} /> : <Icon name= "star-o" size={moderateScale(13)} />}
    </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
const [stars, setStars] = useState(1);

...        

{
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map((x, i) => (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setStars(i)}>
      {stars <= i ? (
        <Icon name="star" color="#ebba34" size={moderateScale(13)} />
      ) : (
        <Icon name="star-o" size={moderateScale(13)} />
      )}
    </TouchableOpacity>
  ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a number for this

```
const [stars, setStars] = useState(0);
```

and then just use this `setStars` method. No need for `setRating` and all this repetition

```
   <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setStars(1)}>
        {stars <= 1 ? 
      <Icon name= "star" color='#ebba34' size={moderateScale(13)} /> : <Icon name= "star-o" size={moderateScale(13)} />}
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you could go about this is to only keep track of how many stars have been "selected" when users click on a specific star.

```
function Rating() {
  const [stars, setStars] = React.useState(0);
  const ratings = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

  return (
    <View style={styles.ratingContainer}>
      {/* Iterate through all `ratings` and render stars for each */}
      {ratings.map(rating => (
        <TouchableOpacity key={rating} onPress={() => setStars(rating)}>
          {/* If `stars` is not 0 and `rating` is less than or equal 
              to the number of `stars`, then show a selected star */}
          {stars !== 0 && rating <= stars ? (
            <Icon name="star" color="#ebba34" size={moderateScale(13)} />
          ) : (
            <Icon name="star-d" size={moderateScale(13)} />
          )}
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ))}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Here's an example:

- [CodeSandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-lumiere-qe6yc?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const Rating = () => {
  const [currentRating, setRating] = useState(0);

  const styles = rating => {
    return {
      width: "20px",
      height: "20px",
      border: "1px solid",
      backgroundColor: stars >= rating ? "green" : "red"
    };
  };

  const rates = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

  const stars = rates.map(rate => {
    return currentRating >= rate ? (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setRating(rate)}>
        <Icon name="star" color="#ebba34" size={moderateScale(13)} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    ) : (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setRating(rate)}>
        <Icon name="star-o" size={moderateScale(13)} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  });

  return <View>{stars}</View>;
```